# how to retrieve location which is saved using geofire on real time database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have saved coordinates of my location using geofire in real time database i.e. in firebase which is updating after every 3 seconds now i want to retreive the coordinates i.e (lat and long) on my map activity but i dont know how to retrieve it . i am new to android studio 
[here is database pic  how the location is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qKNb.png)

the method i have used to store the location in fire base

```
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            FirebaseUser user = fb.getCurrentUser();
            GeoFire geoFire = new 
     GeoFire(databaseReference.child(user.getUid()));
          geoFire.setLocation("location", new  
     GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new 
     GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                  if (error != null) {
                      Toast.makeText(gpdfuel.this, "There was an error 
     saving the location to GeoFire: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(gpdfuel.this, "Location saved on server 
     successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
              }
          });
```

here is database pic  how the location is saved

Comment: You need to use these methods. https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/firebase/geofire/LocationCallback.java

Comment: can you please illustrate more

Comment: You have to implement the interface and use the methods in it . similar to the way you are using onLocationChanged. and than you have to read data in those methods . Like read here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write   . There will be methods like geoFire.getLocation()

Answer (score 0):

In your map ready:

```
 geoFire.getLocation("location", new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        if (location != null) {
            //set marker to display on map
        } else {
            //When location is null
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       //LogDatabase error
    }
});
```

Comment: how it will retrieve location unless it is not used used with databasereference

Comment: mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position().title("")); what to write in position?

Comment: mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position().title("")); bellow the comment // set marker to display on map

Comment: but i have to write something in position()??

Comment: without using LatLan how can i pass something in position( )that is in marker

Comment: you get Latlng, like this                                                                                               Latlng currloc = new Latlng(location.getLatitude,location.getLongitude)